# How to compare the android digital clock to a string value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

guys i have a string value in android: String time.
I have also implemented a digital clock into my xml file. DigitalClock dc;
the string time variable has been coded by myself to whatever the digital clock is plus an hr. so if the digital clock time says 15:00 i have coded the timer string to be 16:00. But I want to continuosly compare the timer to the digital clock so when the digital clock is the same as the timer the textview for the timer changes color. but i wish to do this without the use of a button. can anyone give me ideas of how to continuosly compare the digital clock to my timer variable.

Comment: Instead of comparing you may use AlarmManager class.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run a service. Here is some information on how to set that up: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html